# How to make selected tab in QTabBar to look same when hovered and not hovered

Tags: c++, css, qt

I would like to make active tab (only) to look same when it is hovered and not. 
Inactive(unselected) tabs should respond on hover as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default behavior - active tab looks the same hovered and not hovered.
If you're having problems with that, check if you are overriding that behavior in your stylesheets.

ie:

```
  "QTabBar::tab:selected {"
      "color: blue;"
  "}"
  "QTabBar::tab:hover:selected {"
      "color: red;"
  "}"
```

Comment: Thanks, QTabBar::tab:hover:selected is right what I needed. Sorry, I'm newbie in css and qt.